# updating react component state using this.setState isn't re-rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am updating the react component state using the react.setState() method, the value in the state is getting updated, but the component is not re-rendering with the updated value.

```js
class Mission extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      missonContents: [this.missonContent[0]]
    };
  }

  missonContent = [{
      id: "approach",
      data: "Visit Farmers to review their self-sustenance ideas, provide counselling and suggest suitable options. Rather than one time donation, we support the farmers until they become self-sustain."
    },
    {
      id: "plan",
      data: " Fund 90% for each Farmer’s self sustenance Idea and request the Farmer to contribute 10% to create responsibility."
    },
    {
      id: "goal",
      data: "Develop a working model to make Poor Farmers self-sustain. Involve in Policy advocation at District or State level that supports small farmers."
    }
  ];

  /** This method gets called in the componentDidMount() */
  animateMission() {
    /** some code here */
    // updating the state not rerendering the component
    this.setState({
      "missonContents": [this.missonContent[0], this.missonContent[1]]
    });
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.state["missonContents"]);
    const missionCarousel = this.state["missonContents"].map((missionContent) => {
      // console.log(missionContent);
      return <b > < p id = {
        missionContent.id
      }
      className = "fontsize20" > {
        missionContent.data
      } < /p></b >
    });

    return ( <
      div className = "col l12 m12 s12 margintop50 card" > {
        missionCarousel
      } <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I think the function animateMission() is not in a bind with the class, if it is so what should I do?

Comment: You can bind `animateMission()` by placing this code in your `constructor`: `this.animateMission = this.animateMission.bind(this)` or by changing `animateMission() { ... }` to `animateMission = () => { ... }`. Where are you calling `animateMission()`?

Comment: I am calling animateMission in componentDidMount()

Comment: Please bind the function with auto binding syntax.  animateMission = () => { ...... }

Comment: I changed to function to animateMission = () => {}, but still component not rerendering with the updated data

Comment: @naveen You misspelled `missionContents` in your `state` object. `this.setState()` is setting the updated content to the `missionContents` property but you're rendering the `missonContents` property.

Comment: `componentDidMount()
    {
        this.animateMission();
        setInterval(()=>{
            this.animateMission();
        },20000);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, in your `animstemission()`
After set state call `componentdidmount()` 
I hope it works

- update: I can't see componentdidmount in your code. based on one of your comments I said you can use this, so it may not work if you don't have componentdidmount and call animatedmission in it. And this is not best solution as well

Comment: not working and moreover is it right manually calling componentDidMount()?

Comment: yes, it is fine to call `componentDidMount` manually. sometimes, you want to do something like fetching data once your page has been mounted.

Answer (score 2):

there were some issues in your code.
1) first, bind `animateMission` method in your constructor 
`this.animateMission = this.animateMission.bind(this);`

or use arrow functions.

2) you had some spelling mistakes.
`this.setState({missonContents : [this.missonContent[0],this.missonContents[1]]}); // updating the state not rerendering the component`

here `this.missonContents[1]` and `this.missonContent[0]` have different spellings.